# Heyzap AdColony orientation issue on app going Foreground state

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, orientation, adcolony, heyzap

I'm writing game in Unity3D v5.3.3. The orientation of my game is set only portrait and I'm using Heyzap SDK for ads mediation. I have displaying video ads from Vungle, UnityADS, Heyzap and AdColony providers. After reading a lot of articles about orientation issues, I have done this manual fix in XCode:

[image: Find this return orientations part in UnityAppController.mm file]
***Find this return orientations part in UnityAppController.mm file***

[image: and replace it with this one.]
***and replace it with this one.***

All is working properly, except one case with AdColony ads. After finishing displaying landscape video from AdColony and getting this screen:
[image: Static AdColony screen after playback finish]
***Static AdColony screen after playback finish***

Without closing this screen I'm moving app to background and than back to foreground. AdColony's screen disappears and my game displays in Landscape orientation. All the touch controls are not working after this. So the only way to continue is to kill game and run again.
Please help with solution.

Comment: btw there may be some *particular* solution for this known Hayzap annoyance: I sure hope there is.  I offered unfortunately only a general approach below :/  Sorry I for one can't help more.

Comment: Hi, I'm an engineer at Heyzap. We don't have any control over AdColony rotation (we just call `playVideoAdForZone:withDelegate:`—there isn't any configuration or anything. Do you experience this when using AdColony outside of mediation?

Comment: Hi @MaxGabriel, thanks for answer. I'm using AdColony only in Heyzap. And today I found a real issue, while the video ad from AdColony is playing I send my Unity game to background, and then by opening it again went back to foreground. The video layer gone behind the Unity scene layer, so my game displayed in Landscape, but the video continue to play. I can't see the video, but I can hear the sounds. So the issue is with order of views. Is this a known issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hey @HaykGeghamyan, I haven't heard of that specific issue before, but AdColony does have a bunch of issues relating to orientation. Can you send that info to AdColony support? They're the only ones that can debug/fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MaxGabriel.

Comment: @HaykGeghamyan did you solve your issue?